# How to get dropdown list key value using sugacrm restful api?

Tags: codeigniter, sugarcrm

I am a new `CodeIgniter` framework developer. I have created a sample program for CodeIgniter using `SugarCRM` library rest API concepts. I havintegratedte and connect SugarCRM rest api working. I ha to get dropdown list item value using rest api. Please help me how to get dropdown list value

Thanks

Comment: We have no idea what you have tried if you don't provide code.

Comment: Which version of SugarCRM you are using?

Comment: I am using SugarCRM 6.5

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of enum values you have to make an HTTP request to the sugarcrm. Use a GET verb to request data from:

```
https://<name>.sugarondemand.com//rest/<api_version>/<module_name>/enum/<enum_name>
```

Let's assume that `name = flex, api_version = 11_6, module_name = Leads, enum_name = lead_soruce` then the full url value should be

```
https://flex.sugarondemand.com/rest/v11_6/Leads/enum/lead_source
```

And the full get request (with curl):

```
curl -X GET -H Cache-Control:no-cache -H "Oauth-token":"<access_token>" https://flex.sugarondemand.com/rest/v11_6/Leads/enum/lead_source
```

If you don't have the access token then use the following request to get the access and the refresh tokens

```
curl -X POST -H Cache-Control:no-cache -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
    "grant_type":"password", 
    "client_id":"sugar", 
    "client_secret":"", 
    "username":"<username>", 
    "password":"<user_password>", 
    "platform":"custom_api" 
}' https://<client_name>.sugarondemand.com/rest/v11_6/oauth2/token
```